# Using sed with a regex to replace strings

Tags: bash, sed, terminal

I want to replace some string which contain specific words with another word.

Here is my code

```sh
#!/bin/bash
arr='foo/foo/baz foo/bar/baz foo/baz/baz';

for i in ${arr[@]}; do
  echo $i | sed -e 's|foo/(bar\|baz)/baz|test|g'
done
```

Result

```
foo/foo/baz
foo/bar/baz
foo/baz/baz
```

Expected

```
foo/foo/baz
foo/test/baz
foo/test/baz
```

Comment: either escape parens or add -E flag. pipes as delimiter is not a good idea btw

Comment: Thanks, it was the -E flag. Why are pipes bad?

Comment: You're not creating an array, by the way, it only feels like one because you don't quote `${arr[@]}`. You have to use `arr=('foo/foo/baz' 'foo/bar/baz' 'foo/baz/baz')` to get an array, and then `for i in "${arr[@]}"`. Pipe is not a great idea because it's also a regex special character, I assume.

Comment: @higoka because the pipe has a meaning in the regex language itself. Good alternative delimters are such characters which doesn't have a meaning, like `~` or  `#` for example

Comment: PS: @oguzismail you are right, but pipes are still better than whitespaces :) (saw that yesterday in a post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you can improve. The reason you are using the alternate delimiters `'|'` for the `sed` substitution expression (to avoid the "picket fence" appearance of `\/\/\/` complicates the use of `'|'` as the OR (alternative) regex component. Choose an alternative delimiter that does not also server as part of the regular expression, `'#'` works fine.

Next there is no reason to loop, simply use a *here string* to redirect the contents of `arr` to `sed` and place it all in a *command substitution* with the `"%s\n"` format specifier to provide the newline separated output. (that's a mouthful, but it is actually nothing more than)

```
arr='foo/foo/baz foo/bar/baz foo/baz/baz'
printf "%s\n" $(sed 's#/\(bar\|baz\)/#/test/#g' <<< $arr))
```

**Example Use/Output**

To test it out, just select the expressions above and middle-mouse paste the selection into your terminal, e.g.

```
$ arr='foo/foo/baz foo/bar/baz foo/baz/baz'
> printf "%s\n" $(sed 's#/\(bar\|baz\)/#/test/#g' <<< $arr)
foo/foo/baz
foo/test/baz
foo/test/baz
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
sed -e 's/\(bar\|baz\)\//test\//g'
```